# How does one tell how fast or slow a function grows?

Tags: performance, big-o, rank

Can you rank these in terms of fastest to slowest growing and explain the reasoning why

1 (constant),
log2n (logarithmic),
n (linear),
n * log2 n (“n log n”),
n2 (quadratic),

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: Take a large n, like 10000, and substitute it in each case.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to decide for two function which one grows asymptotically faster, just calculate the limit of the quotient. So for two functions `f(n)` and `g(n)` calculate `lim f(n)/g(n)`. If it is infinity `f` grows faster, if it is zero `g` grows faster and if the result is something else, they grow with the same rate.

At least for all school examples, this should work for most cases and avoids the problem of finding a "large" number. It is not always clear if a number is large in the context of a function. E.g. `f(n) = log(n)`, `g(n) = 2^-20 * n`. `g` grows faster than `f`, but `f(2^20) = 20` and `g(2^20) = 1`.

In real life one would need to use `lim sup` instead and sometimes it is even more complicated.